# Convertir Imagen guardada en resource.mipmap a Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Tengo una imágen en la carpeta `mipmap` de mi proyecto, quisiera convertir esa imagen a un `Bitmap`.
He intentado de esta forma pero no me funciona ya que me dice que

> `(R.mipmap.imagen_deseada)` no puede ser aplicado a este método `(BitmapFactory)`.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.mipmap.imagen_deseada);
articulo.setImg(bitmap);
```

**¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?**

Comment: en el segundo comentario viene como poderlo realizar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435806/drawable-to-byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podes realizar es lo siguiente

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.mipmap.imagen_deseada);
articulo.setImg(bitmap);
```

Donde context es `this` (en Activity) o `getActivity()` (en Fragment)

Recorda que el tamaño de la imagen es importante, tanto peso como resoluciones altas podrian traerte un [OutOfMemoryException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError)